# Python 3.5 Bracket and Speech Mark Removal from Lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

Basically,I have fully created code for my work, which is to create an efficient program that manages to ask 10 basic arithmetic questions at complete random and is mark-able. But when I run it the questions are displayed so the brackets and speech marks are seen, I don't want that. Here's the code and what it does

[Code Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHyA4.png)

Comment: Post the code as *text* in the body of your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem here is that question is a list. You want it to be a concatenated string. Instead of

```
question = [a, b, c]
```

you want something like

```
question = str(a) + b + str(c)
```

Note that you need to convert both numbers to strings before you can concatenate them with your operator, which is represented by a string. Have fun coding!